# Debugging service bus based .NET applications

Tags: nservicebus, servicebus, azureservicebus, azure-queues, azure-servicebus-queues

Lot of developers using service bus to integrate some parts of an application. It doesn't matter which platform do you use for service bus. For example, it could be Azure Service Bus Queue which integrates web application and cloud service.

It's interesting how you working with such apps locally. Do you install Azure Service Bus on each local developer station? Or maybe you use some test messages queue on server for all developers? Or even have a mock for queue?

It would be fine to see how experienced guys solves this problem in real world application. Any comments would be helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Would the read me [in the NServiceBus.Azure.Samples](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Azure.Samples) help?

Comment: (link has grown stale)